# Can someone explain what '[P in keyof O]: O[P];' means?

Tags: typescript

I am a typescript starter and need to create a passport strategy. I stumbled across a line which I completely don't understand (complete code see [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/112cc3e073ee0b01bbb705a6d6f2898c70a71663/types/passport/index.d.ts#L127)).

```
type StrategyCreated<T, O = T & StrategyCreatedStatic> = {
    [P in keyof O]: O[P];
};
```

Can someone explain in plain English what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It a mapped type. You can read mode about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). The basic idea is that it maps a given type (`O` in your case) to another type.

It does this by iterating each key from O (`keyof O`) in the `P` type parameter (`[P in keyof O]`) and assigning a new type for that key.  In this case the type is the same as the original type of the `P` property in `O` (`O[P]`).

This particular type just maps `O` (which is an intersection of `T` and `StrategyCreatedStatic`) to a type with the same properties as the original intersection. The aim is probably to remove the intersection from the resulting type.

Answer (score 1):

The `keyof O` part is a list of all keys of an **O**bject.
`P in` declares that the value of P should be contained in a list of possible values which in your example would be the keys of `O`, which is actually just a proxy for the type `T & StrategyCreatedStatic`. So the line reads "[Properties contained in the keys of type O]: O[P];" "O[P]" determines the value type of the **P**roperty.

As an example:

```
interface Foo {
    hello: string;
    world: number;
}

type StrategyCreated<T, O = T & StrategyCreatedStatic> = {
    [P in keyof O]: O[P];
};

const a: StrategyCreated<Foo> = { hello: "one", world: 2 }; // valid
const b: StrategyCreated<Foo> = { foo: true, bar: false }; // invalid
```